# Denormalize into pipe separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to create a SQL Server function to “join” multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-su)

I have a tablle like this:

```
cust   acc
-----------
a      1
b      2
b      3
c      4
c      5
c      6
```

I want to denormalize above into the following form

```
cust    acc
---------------
a       1
b       2|3
c       4|5|6
```

please note that the acc column should now contain a pipe delimited list of accounts for any customer. Also the possible number of accounts for a customer can be variable.

how to do this using SQL ?

Comment: which data base ? my sql or sql sever ?

Comment: Which rdbms do you use? MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL,...?

Comment: I am using SQL server to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT cust, acc = 
    STUFF((SELECT '| ' +CAST( acc as varchar(20))
           FROM <table> b 
           WHERE b.cust = a.cust 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM <table> a
GROUP BY cust
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adcc6/1)

Comment: i got this to work after modifications but the pipe delimited list is being written into files and links are provided in the answerset. I am using teradata sql assistant to run queries on a sql server database. any ideas how to stop this behaviour and force the pipe delimited list to be displayed in the answer set?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group by Cust (Something like `Group_Concate` in MySQL) there is no any method for it in SQL Server.
So try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT cust
        FROM    t
        ) table2
    CROSS APPLY
        (SELECT  CASE ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER(ORDER BY acc) 
          WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ' | ' END + 
          (cast(acc as varchar))
        FROM    t table3
        WHERE   table3.cust = table2.cust
        ORDER BY acc
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) table3(acc)
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8e86/10)

Also see this: [Group columns into multiple rows and Group_concate like MySQL in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912740/group-columns-into-multiple-rows-and-group-concate-like-mysql-in-sql-server)

Comment: i got this to work after modifications but the pipe delimited list is being written into files and links are provided in the answerset. I am using teradata sql assistant to run queries on a sql server database. any ideas how to stop this behaviour and force the pipe delimited list to be displayed in the answer set?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select cust,
STUFF((select '|'+cast(acc as varchar) from c1 where c1.cust = c2.cust for XML   path('')),1,1,'') as acc from c1 c2
group by cust
```